# UIImagePickerController not presented in iPad issue

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to present UIImagepickerController to open Image Gallery.Its working fine in iPhone but in iPad app crashed with the following error **"Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'**"

**P.S:** my app will support portrait only in iPhone. And landscape orientation in iPad.Any suggestion to resolve this issue?.

Answer (score 0):

"On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController" For iPad, you should present it in a UIPopoverController instead of using direct present. This should fix the issue.

Add a strong property for the UIPopoverController

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popOver;
```

The popover should be dismissed in the delegate methods:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
```

Than write below code in your .m file.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.selectedImageView.bounds inView:self.selectedImageView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
self.popOver = popover;
} else {
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```